# Проблема с шифрованием данных с использованием Fingerprint на Xiaomi

Tags: android, шифрование, криптография, aes

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с ошибкой шифрования. Использую официальную поддержку Android SDK для fingerprint. На официальном сайте есть пример приложения с отпечатком. Так вот оно не работает на **Xiaomi Redmi 3S**.
Инициализация билдера ключей выглядит так:

```
KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder builder = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(keyName,
    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT |
            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
    .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
    .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
    .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);
```

Инициализация сайфера обычная:

```
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
```

После прикладывания пальца в коллбэке вызывается шифрование:

```
byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(SECRET_MESSAGE.getBytes());
```

И падает исключение `javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException`. Перерыл много инфы, пробовал разные алгоритмы шифрования, ассиметричное шифрование, добавление байтов, но не смог побороть проблему. Единственное, что помогает, это выставить флаг `setUserAuthenticationRequired(false)`, только в этом случае работает, но сводит на "нет" смысл использования отпечатка.
На паре англоязычных форумов находил подобные проблемы с Xiaomi, но ответов там нет.

Полный текст основного класса (взят с оф сайта sdk):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private static final String DIALOG_FRAGMENT_TAG = "myFragment";
private static final String SECRET_MESSAGE = "Very secret message";
private static final String KEY_NAME_NOT_INVALIDATED = "key_not_invalidated";
static final String DEFAULT_KEY_NAME = "default_key";

private KeyStore mKeyStore;
private KeyGenerator mKeyGenerator;
private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        mKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get an instance of KeyStore", e);
    }
    try {
        mKeyGenerator = KeyGenerator
                .getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get an instance of KeyGenerator", e);
    }
    Cipher defaultCipher;
    Cipher cipherNotInvalidated;
    try {
        defaultCipher = Cipher.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/"
                + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + "/"
                + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);
        cipherNotInvalidated = Cipher.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/"
                + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + "/"
                + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get an instance of Cipher", e);
    }
    mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    KeyguardManager keyguardManager = getSystemService(KeyguardManager.class);
    FingerprintManager fingerprintManager = getSystemService(FingerprintManager.class);
    Button purchaseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.purchase_button);
    Button purchaseButtonNotInvalidated = (Button) findViewById(
            R.id.purchase_button_not_invalidated);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        purchaseButtonNotInvalidated.setEnabled(true);
        purchaseButtonNotInvalidated.setOnClickListener(
                new PurchaseButtonClickListener(cipherNotInvalidated,
                        KEY_NAME_NOT_INVALIDATED));
    } else {
        // Hide the purchase button which uses a non-invalidated key
        // if the app doesn't work on Android N preview
        purchaseButtonNotInvalidated.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.purchase_button_not_invalidated_description)
                .setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (!keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure()) {
        // Show a message that the user hasn't set up a fingerprint or lock screen.
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Secure lock screen hasn't set up.\n"
                        + "Go to 'Settings -> Security -> Fingerprint' to set up a fingerprint",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        purchaseButton.setEnabled(false);
        purchaseButtonNotInvalidated.setEnabled(false);
        return;
    }

    // Now the protection level of USE_FINGERPRINT permission is normal instead of dangerous.
    // See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#USE_FINGERPRINT
    // The line below prevents the false positive inspection from Android Studio
    // noinspection ResourceType
    if (!fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) {
        purchaseButton.setEnabled(false);
        // This happens when no fingerprints are registered.
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Go to 'Settings -> Security -> Fingerprint' and register at least one fingerprint",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    createKey(DEFAULT_KEY_NAME, true);
    createKey(KEY_NAME_NOT_INVALIDATED, false);
    purchaseButton.setEnabled(true);
    purchaseButton.setOnClickListener(
            new PurchaseButtonClickListener(defaultCipher, DEFAULT_KEY_NAME));
}

/**
 * Initialize the {@link Cipher} instance with the created key in the
 * {@link #createKey(String, boolean)} method.
 *
 * @param keyName the key name to init the cipher
 * @return {@code true} if initialization is successful, {@code false} if the lock screen has
 * been disabled or reset after the key was generated, or if a fingerprint got enrolled after
 * the key was generated.
 */
private boolean initCipher(Cipher cipher, String keyName) {
    try {
        mKeyStore.load(null);
        SecretKey key = (SecretKey) mKeyStore.getKey(keyName, null);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        return true;
    } catch (KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | UnrecoverableKeyException | IOException
            | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e);
    }
}

/**
 * Proceed the purchase operation
 *
 * @param withFingerprint {@code true} if the purchase was made by using a fingerprint
 * @param cryptoObject the Crypto object
 */
public void onPurchased(boolean withFingerprint,
        @Nullable FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject) {
    if (withFingerprint) {
        // If the user has authenticated with fingerprint, verify that using cryptography and
        // then show the confirmation message.
        assert cryptoObject != null;
        tryEncrypt(cryptoObject.getCipher());
    } else {
        // Authentication happened with backup password. Just show the confirmation message.
        showConfirmation(null);
    }
}

// Show confirmation, if fingerprint was used show crypto information.
private void showConfirmation(byte[] encrypted) {
    findViewById(R.id.confirmation_message).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if (encrypted != null) {
        TextView v = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.encrypted_message);
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        v.setText(Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, 0 /* flags */));
    }
}

/**
 * Tries to encrypt some data with the generated key in {@link #createKey} which is
 * only works if the user has just authenticated via fingerprint.
 */
private void tryEncrypt(Cipher cipher) {
    try {
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(SECRET_MESSAGE.getBytes());
        showConfirmation(encrypted);
    } catch (BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to encrypt the data with the generated key. "
                + "Retry the purchase", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to encrypt the data with the generated key." + e.getMessage());
    }
}

/**
 * Creates a symmetric key in the Android Key Store which can only be used after the user has
 * authenticated with fingerprint.
 *
 * @param keyName the name of the key to be created
 * @param invalidatedByBiometricEnrollment if {@code false} is passed, the created key will not
 *                                         be invalidated even if a new fingerprint is enrolled.
 *                                         The default value is {@code true}, so passing
 *                                         {@code true} doesn't change the behavior
 *                                         (the key will be invalidated if a new fingerprint is
 *                                         enrolled.). Note that this parameter is only valid if
 *                                         the app works on Android N developer preview.
 *
 */
public void createKey(String keyName, boolean invalidatedByBiometricEnrollment) {
    // The enrolling flow for fingerprint. This is where you ask the user to set up fingerprint
    // for your flow. Use of keys is necessary if you need to know if the set of
    // enrolled fingerprints has changed.
    try {
        mKeyStore.load(null);
        // Set the alias of the entry in Android KeyStore where the key will appear
        // and the constrains (purposes) in the constructor of the Builder

        KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder builder = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(keyName,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT |
                        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                // Require the user to authenticate with a fingerprint to authorize every use
                // of the key
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);

        // This is a workaround to avoid crashes on devices whose API level is < 24
        // because KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder#setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment is only
        // visible on API level +24.
        // Ideally there should be a compat library for KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder but
        // which isn't available yet.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            builder.setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(invalidatedByBiometricEnrollment);
        }
        mKeyGenerator.init(builder.build());
        mKeyGenerator.generateKey();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
            | CertificateException | IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private class PurchaseButtonClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    Cipher mCipher;
    String mKeyName;

    PurchaseButtonClickListener(Cipher cipher, String keyName) {
        mCipher = cipher;
        mKeyName = keyName;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        findViewById(R.id.confirmation_message).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.encrypted_message).setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // Set up the crypto object for later. The object will be authenticated by use
        // of the fingerprint.
        if (initCipher(mCipher, mKeyName)) {

            // Show the fingerprint dialog. The user has the option to use the fingerprint with
            // crypto, or you can fall back to using a server-side verified password.
            FingerprintAuthenticationDialogFragment fragment
                    = new FingerprintAuthenticationDialogFragment();
            fragment.setCryptoObject(new FingerprintManager.CryptoObject(mCipher));
            boolean useFingerprintPreference = mSharedPreferences
                    .getBoolean(getString(R.string.use_fingerprint_to_authenticate_key),
                            true);
            if (useFingerprintPreference) {
                fragment.setStage(
                        FingerprintAuthenticationDialogFragment.Stage.FINGERPRINT);
            } else {
                fragment.setStage(
                        FingerprintAuthenticationDialogFragment.Stage.PASSWORD);
            }
            fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), DIALOG_FRAGMENT_TAG);
        } else {
            // This happens if the lock screen has been disabled or or a fingerprint got
            // enrolled. Thus show the dialog to authenticate with their password first
            // and ask the user if they want to authenticate with fingerprints in the
            // future
            FingerprintAuthenticationDialogFragment fragment
                    = new FingerprintAuthenticationDialogFragment();
            fragment.setCryptoObject(new FingerprintManager.CryptoObject(mCipher));
            fragment.setStage(
                    FingerprintAuthenticationDialogFragment.Stage.NEW_FINGERPRINT_ENROLLED);
            fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), DIALOG_FRAGMENT_TAG);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Покажите полный код инициализации ключа и шифра - не вижу где и как вы выбираете сам `cipher`

Comment: Добавил весь код основного класса.
Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Вроде все норм. Тестировали на эмуляторе?

Comment: На эмуляторе нет. Попросил проверить на самсунге, работает говорят. Похоже с Xiaomi прошивкой всё-таки проблема...

Comment: протестируйте на эмуляторе - эмулятор поддерживает шифрование через *Fingerprint*